# SQL Join with subquery counting number of records with the same id in a different table

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so I have three(3) tables that i want to join together

- tableA is the main details and primary key is `row_id` autoincremented
- tableB is the exteded details and primary/foreign key is `row_id` coming from tableA
- tableC stores unordered ratings and comments for a particular `row_id`

I want to join all these tables so that I can see all details plus the number of instances in tableC for a `row_id` and the avg rating.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `tableA` A
LEFT JOIN  `tableB` B 
      ON A.`row_id` = B.`row_id` 
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT COUNT( 1 ) AS  'count', Avg(`row_rating`) AS  'avg'
     FROM  `tableC` 
     GROUP BY tableC.`row_id`
)C 
     ON C.`row_id` = A.`row_id` 

ORDER BY  C.`avg` ASC
```

The result of this query combines all properly but the same count and avg is displayed in all rows.

Comment: This isn't php. Don't tag it as so..

Comment: But the content is mysql and not including php/php question of any kind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to group the records by `row_id` in inner query. In which case, you need to `SELECT` `row_id` instead of `COUNT(1)`, try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `tableA` A
LEFT JOIN  `tableB` B 
      ON A.`row_id` = B.`row_id` 
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT row_id, Avg(`row_rating`) AS  'avg'
     FROM  `tableC` 
     GROUP BY tableC.`row_id`
)C 
     ON C.`row_id` = A.`row_id` 

ORDER BY  C.`avg` ASC
```

Comment: That was it, had to add the `row_id` into the sub-query. Only thing is it causes duplicate data in the row. But it should work for what i need.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: To remove dups, you might need to use another GROUP BY in outer query. However, it's difficult to comment without knowing the exact output.